Usage of あれでよく in this sentence?

うるさいんだもん! お前あれでよく起きないね. 私は寝つきも寝起きも悪いんだよ

The character is complaining to his girlfriend that her alarm clock is too noisy. So he turned it down and now say girlfriend is late.
He tells her "It's so noisy! I'm bad at waking up and falling asleep"
But what is the exact nuance of あれでよく here? "With that"?

He tells her "It's so noisy! I'm bad at waking up and falling asleep" -- 「うるさいんだもん! お前あれでよく起きないね.」 and 「私は寝つきも寝起きも悪いんだよ」 are said by different people, right? Otherwise it wouldn't make much sense. The male character says "Your alarm clock is too noisy (so I turned it down). How can you not wake up with that big noise?" and his gf relpies "I'm bad at falling asleep, and waking up too! (so I need that big noise from my alram clock)."

あれで is simply "with that (noise)".
This よく is a sarcastic よく explained in the following questions:

Meaning of よく住める
善くも as opposed to よく
interpretting よくこれだけの言い訳が出るものだ
What does this conversation from a novel mean? 「よく命が続いとるなあ」 「いや、呆れたもんだよ」
Could someone explain the ironic(?) use of よくいうよ?


お前あれでよく起きないね

How can you not wake up with that (noise)?
It's surprising you don't wake up with all that noise.


